# Mbtiles from dedicated server to mapbox account

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles

I process Landsat Imagery on a dedicated server and generate mbtiles.
Is there a way to upload the mbtiles files straight from my server to my Mapbox account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not officially, but kinda. I ran into this last week and the best solution was to install firefox on the server and ssh to it. From there it's just like browsing normally, you just select the mbtiles from the server's filesystem.

On ubuntu:

- sudo apt-get install firefox
- ssh to the server with the -X flag, example: ssh -X root@123.456.789
- then run "firefox www.mapbox.com/data"

Login and upload your data from there like normal. It is kinda laggy but works.